# How can make content editable Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on wordpress site, I want to make all pages content editable from backend i.e admin panel,every page site have many sections so not easy to handle only with page content area.
What is the most easiest and preferable way to make all content editable.

Answer (score 0):

add page in the admin panel with the contents that you needed to show in the front page. then using the `page ID` you can get the contents in your template page.

```
<?php 
$id=47; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;  
?>
```